# When launching apps the app window is not in foreground

Tags: 22.04, focus

Since installing 22.04, I've noticed that many times (not all), if I launch an app, I receive an informational dialog saying that the app is ready instead of having the app's window being displayed in the foreground.  If I click on the dialog, the window is foregrounded.  This seems like odd behavior.  Is this correctable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default behavior of Gnome Shell, where applications that are loaded do not automatically gain focus - although the behavior is quite inconsistent. The classical extension  NoAnnoyance appears to be dead, but fortunately there is a maintained fork [NoAnnoyance v2](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/) by bjoerndaase. Some other extensions such as [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) or [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) also include such option.

Comment: Thanks, works as advertised